# Repoint legacy app to new oracle home hierarchy

Tags: oracle, vb6, oracle11gr2, oracle-home

I am working on 2 virtual machines to test legacy application functionality on new platforms, with an OS & DB upgrade.  The application that is being tested on the new client (Win7Prox64) was written in VB6.  (It's pretty old!)  When the application launches, it opens a form that allows users to login.
The old DB it connected to was 11G on Server2003SP2 32bit box and the app ran on a 32bit XP client.  (The new VM for the new server for test is 2008R2x64).

The legacy app has the the following declared: ("frmLogin.frm")
(The app checks the registry for the location of tnsnames by assigning the correct directory paths to these Const's)

```
Private Const MODULE_NAME = "frmLogin"
Private Const REG_APP_KEY = "Software\ORACLE\HOME"
Private Const REG_APP_PATH = "Oracle_Home"
Private Const REG_ALL_HOMES = "Software\Oracle\ALL_HOMES"
Private Const REG_LAST_HOME = "LAST_HOME"
Private Const REG_MYAPP_KEY = "Software\company\myapp"
Private Const MYAPP_APP_KEY = "Database Host Name"
```

I assume I have to change these constants to the new hierarchy found with 11GR2 to make it work correctly, how do I check and update these?  I'm not sure it's as easy as just changing the directories above, but I could be wrong.

Any tips welcome.

EDIT: I notice 11GR2 on Win7 64 registry entries are alot different to XP 32bit with 11G.  Both in layout and content.  LAST_HOME for example doesn't seem to exist on Win7, any advice?

I hard coded a reference to the location of tnsnames.ora into the app, and I know that it runs (and seems to run well) on the new 64bit client, but I cannot hardcode it for each and every client machine it will reside on, so need to re-point the directories correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through every registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_***`, since there are possibly multiple installations on one system.

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` in the registry, then check every sub key if it starts with `KEY_`. (pick the first if you don't care, if you do, go through every one)

In those keys you will find:

- The `TNS_ADMIN`, the deviating location where the tnsnames.ora will be saved;
- The `ORACLE_HOME` where you need to append `network\admin` where the tnsnames.ora will generally be found.

Comment: Not sure I follow, this is only what I see: http://i.imgur.com/J2SP0mE.jpg & totally different hierarchy and keys on XP: http://i.imgur.com/NIIMtqP.jpg (The app works on this, I need to modify my vb6 code so it works on the first image)

Comment: This is how the code currently computes the location in XP: strOHD = GetRegistryKey(strKey & GetRegistryKey(REG_ALL_HOMES, REG_LAST_HOME, bLocal_Machine:=True), _
                        REG_APP_PATH, bLocal_Machine:=True)
  
 strfilename = strOHD & "\network\admin\tnsnames.ora"

Comment: I can get it to work in Win7x64 if I modify it to this: '//strfilename = "C:\app\username\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora" But this hardcoding is not suitable.

Comment: @GrumP: take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267908) to find all sub keys. The code is too extensive to past here.

Comment: Tried that link with 2012 & 2008 Visual Studio's and both littered with errors.

Comment: Yes, have it working now.  I foolishly wasn't running for vb6.  It compiles now.  How exactly it is helpful, isn't clear though.

Comment: The link you provided creates a small app that lists registry entries, it doesn't appear to assist further than viewing regedit does.

Comment: @GrumP: the demo uses `RegEnumKeyEx`. That is the key to your answer. Using that, and the logic below the call, you can iterate through all the keys as suggested in my answer.